# wp-cli plugin update --all does not detect properly installed versions

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

using

```
wp-cli plugin update --all
```

results into:

```
Available plugin updates:
+--------------------+----------+---------+----------------+
| name               | status   | version | update_version |
+--------------------+----------+---------+----------------+
| astra-addon        | inactive | 4.1.6   | 4.1.6          |
| convertpro         | active   | 1.7.6   | 1.7.6          |
| astra-pro-sites    | active   | 3.2.6   | 3.2.6          |
| wp-schema-pro      | active   | 2.7.9   | 2.7.9          |
| ultimate-elementor | inactive | 1.36.17 | 1.36.17        |
| astra-portfolio    | active   | 1.11.5  | 1.11.5         |
+--------------------+----------+---------+----------------+
```

if I rerun the command I am getting the versions installed over and over again and the versions are getting kept displayed in the given table.

Is there any plugin version cache, which needs to be cleaned first?

Or what is the reason for this behavior?